# breakline in string to pdf

Tags: apex, visualforce-component, pdf, string

I have an apex:component controller from where I pass a string to

```
`</messaging:attachment
<c:TrainersListComponent TrainingIdAttr="{!relatedTo.Training__c}" />
```

Which is rendered as PDF: `<messaging:attachment filename="file" renderAs="pdf" >`

How do I pass a brakeline in the string, I tried `string+= '\r\n'`  , `string+= '\n'`, `string+= '<br>/'`  but none of them seam to work

Here is my code:

```
public with sharing class TrainersActeurListController {
    public Id trainingId {get;set;}
    public String trainerListStr;
    //public Trainer__c trainer{get;set;}
    public String getTrainerListStr() {
        List<Trainer__c> trainersList =  new List<Trainer__c>();

        if(String.isNotBlank(trainingId)){
            // Get the list of trainer records related to this training
            try{
                trainersList = [SELECT Trainer__r.FirstName,Trainer__r.Titel__c,Trainer__r.Achter_titel__c,Trainer__r.Voorletters__C, Trainer__r.LastName, Trainer__r.Salutation , Trainer__r.MiddleName, Trainer__r.Title
                                FROM Trainer__c
                                WHERE Training__c =: trainingId];
                if(trainersList != null && !trainersList.isEmpty() && trainersList.size() > 0){             
                    trainerListStr = '';
                    for( Trainer__c trainer : trainersList){
                     if(trainer.Trainer__r.Salutation!= null){
                            trainerListStr += trainer.Trainer__r.Salutation+ ' ';
                        }
                        if(trainer.Trainer__r.Titel__c != null){                        
                            trainerListStr += trainer.Trainer__r.Titel__c+ ' ';
                        }
                        if(trainer.Trainer__r.Voorletters__c!= null){
                            trainerListStr += trainer.Trainer__r.Voorletters__c + ' ';
                        }
                         if(trainer.Trainer__r.MiddleName!= null){
                            trainerListStr += trainer.Trainer__r.MiddleName+ ' ';
                        }
                        if(trainer.Trainer__r.LastName != null){
                            trainerListStr += trainer.Trainer__r.LastName +' ' ;
                        }
                         if(trainer.Trainer__r.Achter_titel__C!= null){
                            trainerListStr += trainer.Trainer__r.Achter_titel__C + ' ';
                        }
                         if(trainer.Trainer__r.FirstName!= null){
                         system.debug(trainerListStr);
                            trainerListStr += '(' + trainer.Trainer__r.FirstName + '), <br/>';
                        }
                    }
                    trainerListStr = trainerListStr.removeEnd(', ');
                }
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                System.debug('Exception in fetching trainer details : ' + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
        return trainerListStr;
    }'       '<apex:component controller="TrainersActeurListController" access="global">
    <apex:attribute name="TrainingIdAttr" type="Id" description="Id of the training" assignTo="{!trainingId}"/>
    {!trainerListStr}   
</apex:component>'  '<c:TrainersListComponent TrainingIdAttr="{!relatedTo.Training__c}" />
```

Comment: Can you try using a <br/> tag and use the string in outputText with escape=false. Note that it has some security concerns.

Comment: You can use outputText inside your component where in you're displaying the value. If thats possible.

Comment: @RahulSharma  where do i place the escape=false. because <c:TrainersListComponent has no outputText tag. Do i need to place it like this? '<apex:outputtext escape="false"><c:TrainersListComponent TrainingIdAttr="{!relatedTo.Training__c}" /><br/></apex:outputtext>'

Comment: Instead of displaying the value in component directly, use outputText. Maybe share you're code.

Comment: you could just do something like `<apex:outputText label="" value="" />`

Comment: @RahulSharma I added my code